# I want to group time interval based on given tolerance in postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
create table sample(id integer, name varchar(100), timeint time);

insert into sample values(1, 'aaa', '00:00:01');
insert into sample values(1, 'aaa', '00:00:01');
insert into sample values(1, 'aaa', '00:00:02');
insert into sample values(1, 'aaa', '00:00:03');
insert into sample values(1, 'aaa', '00:00:04');
insert into sample values(2, 'bbb', '00:00:01');
insert into sample values(2,'bbb', '00:00:02');
insert into sample values(2, 'bbb', '00:00:03');

select id,name,timeint,count(timeint) from sample
group by id,name,timeint;
```

------output will be like----

```
1   aaa 00:00:01    2
1   aaa 00:00:02    1
1   aaa 00:00:03    1
1   aaa 00:00:04    1
2   bbb 00:00:01    1
2   bbb 00:00:02    1
2   bbb 00:00:03    1
```

So the above output should be regrouped in such a manner that for same id and name , timeint with 1 sec tolerance should be considered as same

______ expected output _________________

```
1   aaa 00:00:01    3
1   aaa 00:00:03    2
2   bbb 00:00:01    2
2   bbb 00:00:03    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution to your problem requires a recursive CTE.  If all times are accurate to one second and you only want two seconds, there might be a way around that.

However, this solution uses a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive s as (
      select s.id, s.name, s.timeint, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by timeint) as seqnum
      from sample s
      group by s.id, s.name, s.timeint
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, timeint, name, seqnum, timeint as start_timeint, cnt
      from s
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select s.id, s.timeint, s.name, s.seqnum,
             (case when s.timeint <= cte.start_timeint + interval '1 second'
                   then cte.start_timeint else s.timeint
              end),
             s.cnt
      from cte join
           s
           on s.id = cte.id and s.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select  id, name, start_timeint, sum(cnt)
from cte
group by id, name, start_timeint
order by id, start_timeint;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=30c6e33d63fdb1d4e4613e0dc9bc6567) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For this sample data you could apply the logic that all `timeint`s with even number of seconds should be grouped with the previous `timeint` (-1 second):

```
select 
  id, 
  name, 
  timeint - interval '1 seconds' * (mod(extract(second from timeint)::int, 2) = 0)::int  time_int, 
  count(*) counter
from sample
group by id, name, time_int
order by id, name, time_int
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hEDP3M78VcdhFf4tNyUkb4/2).
Results:

```
| id  | name | time_int | counter |
| --- | ---- | -------- | ------- |
| 1   | aaa  | 00:00:01 | 3       |
| 1   | aaa  | 00:00:03 | 2       |
| 2   | bbb  | 00:00:01 | 2       |
| 2   | bbb  | 00:00:03 | 1       |
```